# The ratio of the dependent normal rv and chi rv is?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

(I hope this question may be too easy for some experts here). It is well-known that if $X$ is normal rv and $Y$ is a chi-square rv, then $Z=X/\sqrt{Y/n}$ follows student's $t$  distribution, where $n$ is the degrees of freedom of $Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ need to be independent.

However, what comes if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent? More specifically, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal rvs, then $Z=X_1/\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ would follow what kind of distribution?

Comment: The initial assertion is incorrect unless you specify that $X$ has zero mean and unit variance (although obviously changing the variance only rescales $Z$).  Upon adopting the same assumption for $X_1$ and $X_2$--namely, that they have zero means and their variances are equal, integration gives the PDF of $Z$ as $dz/(\pi\sqrt{1-z^2})$ (a rescaled Beta distribution). If they have different variances and $\sigma^2$ is the ratio of the variance of $X_2$ to that of $X_1$, the PDF generalizes to $\frac{\sigma }{\pi  \sqrt{1-z^2} \left(1+\left(\sigma^2-1\right)\right)z^2}$ (which can be *trimodal*).

Answer (score 6):

Let $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be independently and Normally distributed with common mean $0$ and common standard deviation $\sigma$.  The ratio

$$Z = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2 + \cdots + X_n^2}} = \frac{X\cdot \nu}{|X||\nu|}$$

for $\nu = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ is the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $\nu$.  We could just as well replace $\nu$ with an independent multinormal vector $Y$ having the same distribution as $X$, because the correlation coefficient is the cosine of the angle and the distribution of the angle between independent $X$ and $Y$ is the distribution of the angle between $X$ and *any* fixed vector (we may rotate $Y$ into that fixed vector without changing the distribution of $X$).  If you have any trouble believing this, consider the case $n=2$, where the claim is that the distribution of the angle made between a random point on the circle and the y-axis is the same as the distribution of the angle made between two random points on the circle.

Consequently, **$Z$ has the same distribution as the *sample correlation coefficient* for a sample of size $n+1$ from a Binormal distribution with correlation parameter $\rho=0$.**  (The sample size is one greater than $n$ because in computing the sample correlation, one degree of freedom is lost through the centering process.)  We may therefore avail ourselves of the [well known result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Use_the_exact_distribution) that this distribution has pdf

$$f(z) = \frac{(1-z^2)^{(n+1-4)/2}}{B(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n+1-2}{2})} = \frac{(1-z^2)^{(n-3)/2}}{2^{n-2} B(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})}.$$

**This is a Beta$(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})$ distribution scaled to the interval $[-1, 1]$.**

If instead of $X_1$ we use any nonzero linear combination $Z_a = a_1 X_1 + \cdots + a_n X_n$, upon writing this as $|a|(\alpha_1 X_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n X_n)$ with $\alpha_1^2 + \cdots + \alpha_n^2=1$, the same argument applies with the same result, showing that $Z_a$ has the same distribution as $|a|Z$: it is a Beta distribution rescaled to the interval $[-|a|, |a|]$.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend* on the form of the dependence. In many (almost all) cases, it won't be any well-known distribution.

* pun unintended

For the specific question, an answer may be possible.

Note that if the $X_i$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $Z^2$ would have a beta distribution.

Comment: Thx a lot. And, so if $Z=(a*X_1+b*X_2)/\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$, a and b are constant, then the distribution of $Z$ is generally unknown?

Comment: Well, I can't say that *I* know.

Comment: The distribution of that $Z$ can readily be worked out (with just simple algebra) when the $X_i$ both have zero mean and equal variances by applying the results of my comment (anent the question) to the independent Normal variates $Y_1=a X_1 + b X_2$ and $Y_2=b X_2 - a X_1$.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks for your comments. However, I don't understand it very clearly. So, let $X_i$ are i.i.i. $N(0,1)$ rvs, one can calculate the PDF of Z according to the integration.(Using convolution?) When there are constants, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, what if there are more than 2 rvs, that is $Z=a_1*X_1+...a_d*X_d/\sqrt(X_1^2+...+X_d^2)$?

Comment: The same approach works. The integration is perhaps most easily done using Fisher's geometric methods.  (More formally, change to spherical coordinates and exploit the symmetry.)