# QR decomposition of normally distributed matrices

Tags: normal-distribution, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, chi-distribution

Assume $M$ is an $N \times k$ Gaussian matrix, i.e., its entries are i.i.d. standard normal random variables, with $N>>k$. Take $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dotsc ,\lambda_N)$ for some fixed real scalars. I am interested in finding the p.d.f. of the $N \times k$ "unitary" matrix $Q$ from the QR decomposition of $DM$ (and possibly $D^2M$, etc.).

It is known that if $k=N$ and $D=I_N$, the identity matrix, then $Q$ is distributed with respect to the [Haar measure on the Lie group of orthonormal matrices of order $N$](http://www.ams.org/notices/200705/fea-mezzadri-web.pdf).  Can you provide any insight on the general case for $k<N$ and/or general $D$?

I also tried to look for the simplest case, i.e., $k=1$. Then the QR decomposition coincides with a simple normalization. I have found [this result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52447/the-ratio-of-the-dependent-normal-rv-and-chi-rv-is) for common variance, i.e., the case $\lambda_1=\dotsc =\lambda_N$. Can this be easily generalized for the general case with different $\lambda_i$?

I attempted in the simplest case to scale the matrix $M$ (which is for $k=1$ just an $N$ dimensional random vector). Indeed, then the above-mentioned result is applicable and one gets $$DM=DUR, $$
where $UR$ is the QR decomposition of $M$ and the p.d.f. of entries of $U$ is known from the above. Nonetheless, I haven't found any easy way to connect the p.d.f. of $DU$ with the one of $Q$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @whumber is the one to give credit for the special case. He/she also mentioned the p.d.f. in the comment for $N=2, k=1$, however I do not see the idea of how was this obtained and hence cannot try to generalize it for higher dimensions $N$.

Comment: What are the $\lambda_i$?  Are they arbitrary values or have they somehow been derived from $M$ itself (such as eigenvalues of $MM^\prime$)?

Comment: In general they are arbitrary. At the moment I am focusing on the case where $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_i=\lambda^{i-1}$ for $i=2,3,\dotsc ,N$, i.e., they are geometrically decaying with a fixed parameter $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @whumber , could you please clarify the simplest case with $N=2$ and $k=1$?